# google.setOnLoadCallback does not work/does not wait until anything is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, google-visualization

That's pretty much it, the call seems to do absolutely nothing.

If I debug the page in Chrome, put a breakpoint right after the call to

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar', 'table'] });
```

and literally wait 5-10 seconds for the loading to finish, then proceed, it is fine. Otherwise, if I let 'setOnLoadCallback' try to do it's thing, it will throw

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined'

The error is thrown on:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Edit:

I should also note that in all examples I've found, when calling

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

All the examples are as above, without including the brackets '()' at the end of the function, i.e.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());
```

However, the only way it actually works for me, is WITH the brackets, yet there are no examples where people include the  brackets.

Comment: FYI : Those brackets are called _paranthesis_ `( )`  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart())` (with paranthesis) should not work at all, so that sounds a little bit strange. `setOnLoadCallback` expects the *name* of a function it can call, not the *execution* of a function.

`setOnLoadCallback` is a general google feature. It is also triggered by `google.load("jquery", "1.9.1")` etc. It could be the case that somewhere in your code another library is loaded by `google.load()` and by that triggering your `setOnLoadCallBack` prematurely.

So to be absolutely certain that your callback is actually triggered when the visualization library is loaded, and not by something else, you can set the callback directly on `load()` instead of relying on `setOnLoadCallback()` :

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', 
     { packages: ['corechart', 'bar', 'table'], callback: drawChart });
```

Comment: Some quick testing, this seems to work much better. I checked to see if I was loading any other Google libraries anywhere, and I was, but removing it didn't seem to have any effect. I'm still really unsure why it won't call my function in the 'google.setOnLoadCallback(  drawChart );' call.

In any case, your suggestion is a better way to do it. Thanks