# Google charts (jsapi) into angular2 component

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-visualization, angular

I'm struggling to create an angular2 component that would call google chart api and display a google-chart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start). This usually leads to unexplained mistakes or just the browser loading forever.

EDIT : full updated test files added below

See also in plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/3a5pwbG4wnRDuTYj4hB3).

To be more specific, these are the test files I use to identify the point where things start to go wrong :

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.46/angular2.dev.js">    </script>

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }
  });
  System.import('./app.ts');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

And then, app.ts

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template:`
<h1>Demo component my-app</h1>
<div id="cc" (click)="test($event)">Click me</div>
`
})
class AppComponent {

constructor() {
console.log("Constructor was called");
}

test(event) {
console.log("Event :",event);
console.log("Test :", google);
console.log("Document object by id",document.getElementById("cc"));

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {

  console.log("Callback is entered ");

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new   google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('cc'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}



  console.log("Google object : ", google);
  console.log("Now, loading visualization api");
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  console.log("Now, setting callback");
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  console.log("Callback was set");
  }

}



bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

And this is what console shows, when I click :

```
Constructor was called
app.ts:18 Event : MouseEvent {isTrusted: true}
app.ts:19 Test : Object {loader: Object}
app.ts:20 Document object by id <div id=​"cc">​Click me​</div>​
app.ts:53 Google object :  Object {loader: Object}
app.ts:54 Now, loading visualization api
app.ts:57 Now, setting callback
app.ts:60 Callback was set
```

Clearly, the callback is never entered into ?!

Anyone can help me sort out this issue ? Many thanks !

Comment: you should add a script tag for the jsapi script in `index.html` and then it will be on the global scope in your component so you don't need to require or import it.

Comment: @rob  Thanks for taking the time to answer ! I realized my question was not specific enough, and edited it. What I am really trying to do is to ensure that I can get a simple graph, such as the quick-start graph example from google-visualisation to run in an angular2  component, before starting to port an existing application currently using angular1, where all my graphs and data structures are based on google-visualization ...

Comment: Chart components of PrimeNG can help. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/piechart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, solved it by using a chart component to call a chart directive. The setter of that directive triggers the drawing. No further need to directly capture/manage drawing events.

1. Load google script from the top index.html file

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">        
     google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
       'packages': ['corechart']
     });
   </script>
   ```
2. Create a "chart" directive to draw google chart (chart.directive.ts)

   ```
   /**
   *      This directive will draw a chart from the array of records provided
   *
   *           Note : the relevant jsapi scripts should be already available
   *                  globally in the window.google object (see index.html)
   **/

   import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from "angular2/core";
   import {CORE_DIRECTIVES } from "angular2/common";

   @Directive({
     selector: "chart",
   })
   export class ChartDirective {

     el: HTMLElement; 
     w: any;  // To store the window, without generating errors in typescript on window.google
     private _content: any[] = [];         

     // Setter for content will trigger drawing (or refreshing)
     @Input()
     set content(c: any[]) {
       console.log("Setting content ...");
       this._content = c;
       this.draw();
     }

     get content() { return this._content; }



     // Constructor inject a ref to the element
     constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
     console.log("Constructing chart directive");
     this.w = window;
     this.el = elementRef.nativeElement; // You cannot use elementRef directly !
     // console.log("Native HTML :", this.el);
     if (!this.w.google) { console.error("Hey ! It seems the needed google script was not loaded ?"); };
     }

   // Do the actual drawing
   draw() {
     // Create the data table.
     let data = new this.w.google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn("date", "Quand");
     data.addColumn("number", "KG");
     let rows = [];
     for (let c in this._content) {
       let d: Date = new Date(this._content[c].quand);
       let k: number = +(this._content[c].kg); // Plus sign to force conversion sting -> number
       // Only take into account records after the 'notBefore date'
       if (d >= this._nbd) rows.push([d, k]);
     }
     data.addRows(rows);
     // Create options
     let options: any = {
       // "width": 600,
       "height": 300,
       "curveType": "function"
     };


     // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
     (new this.w.google.visualization.LineChart(this.el))
       .draw(data, options);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Use the directive in a chart component (chart.component) ...

   ```
   import {Component } from "angular2/core";
   import {CORE_DIRECTIVES } from "angular2/common";

   import {MyModel} from "./mymodel.service.ts";
   import {ChartDirective} from "./chart.directive.ts";


   @Component({
   selector: "chartPage",
   templateUrl: "/components/chart.template.html",
   directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, ChartDirective]        
   })
   export class ChartComponent {     

   }

   // Injecting my data model into chart component ...
   constructor(private model: MyModel) {
     console.log("Constructing chart component");
   };
   ```

   }
4. ... using the following template for the chart

   ```
   <chart [content]="model.content" ></chart>
   ```

Comment: what is `this._nbd` in file `chart.directive.ts`?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but i am still not able to catch this.
can someone please share the working GoogleCharts+Angular2 Project Directory?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when trying to implement google charts into ionic2. Iam not sure what the problem is exactly, but it seems that

```
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

takes too long to load and

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

is never executed. You can bypass this by adding the callback directly to the google.load() like this:

```
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Worked for me! and the charts are loading as desired. All credit for this solution goes to @davidkonrad:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040694

Hope it works!